# Perl - File not found

Tags: perl, excel, cgi, file-not-found

```
#!"C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe"
use CGI;
use strict;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;

my $FileName = "C:\excel\Onsite_Report(15).xlsx";
my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $workbook = $parser->parse($FileName);

die $parser->error(), ".\n" if ( !defined $workbook );

# Following block is used to Iterate through all worksheets
# in the workbook and print the worksheet content 

for my $worksheet ( $workbook->worksheets() ) {

    # Find out the worksheet ranges
    my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
    my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet->col_range();

    for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {
        for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {

            # Return the cell object at $row and $col
            my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );
            next unless $cell;

            print "Row, Col    = ($row, $col)\n";
            print "Value       = ", $cell->value(),       "\n";

        }
    }
}
```

Throws the error `File not found`, but the path is correct. Please advice.
**`EDIT`**
added - `warn -e $FileName ? "File exists":"File does not exist";`
**`ERROR`**

```
Unrecognized escape \O passed through at perltest2.cgi line 6.
File does not exist at perltest2.cgi line 10.
File not found.
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem on my system (Win7). If the error is "File not found", then that is because the parser cannot find your file. Try adding `warn -e $FileName ? "File exists":"File does not exist"` before your die statement to verify that Perl can see the file.

Comment: Also, you really, really should `use warnings`.

Comment: Are you actually using `C:\excel\Onsite_Report(15).xlsx` ?

Comment: Re: Edit: So the script can't see your excel file. Did the new error "unrecognized escape \0" come after you added `use warnings`? It looks like your file contains some weird characters.

Comment: @RobEarl You can use either `\ ` or `/` in paths in Windows.

Comment: @RobEarl Oh, I see. He changed slash to backslash and foolishly did not tell us about it. Yep, that'd do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Unrecognized escape \O passed through at perltest2.cgi line 6.
```

Looks like you have:

```
my $FileName = "C:\excel\Onsite_Report(15).xlsx";
```

Perl sees two escape sequences in this string: `\e` and `\O`. The `\e` doesn't cause an error as it is a valid escape:

> [\e                Escape character.](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html#All-the-sequences-and-escapes)

But the `\O` isn't. Use single quotes so Perl doesn't interpolate the escapes:

```
my $FileName = 'C:\excel\Onsite_Report(15).xlsx';
```